# WCF RIA SERVICES AuthenticationDomainService get additional parameter from User class

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services

AuthenticationDomainService inherit base class AuthenticationBase < User >. In User I have added additional field. I can get name of authenticated user using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. How Can I get my additional property? I dont use membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it through `WebContext.Current.User`.
hope this helps.

//edit:
On the server side,
`YourDomainAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser(IPrincipal principal);` should return what you need.

Comment: yes. It is in client. Where can I get this in server? I just implement method on server what gives me this info from DB.